# Why does the "Disable Device" command show up for only some USB controllers and not others?

Tags: windows-10, usb, device-manager

In Windows 10's Device Manager, one of the USB controllers (8086:1c2d) built into my Intel P67 Express chipset shows a "Disable Device" command, and the other one (8086:1c26) does not (although it still gives "Uninstall"). Why is this?

[image: USB controller context menu showing no disable option]
[image: USB controller context menu showing disable option]

**More info:**

The mechanism for the disabling is the underlying `DN_DISABLEABLE` flag in the device status (`DEVPKEY_Device_DevNodeStatus` from `Devpkey.h`) which you can see in the device details property Status in Device Manager, but that doesn't tell me why the underlying driver would set this for one controller and not for the other if that is indeed what has happened.

[image: device properties dialog for USB controller showing Status with DN_DISABLEABLE flag highlighted]

Comment: Are you on a laptop or a desktop? I am mainly a Mac person, but I know that on many modern machines the built-in parts — keyboard, trackpad, camera, etc… — are part of the USB bus. And I think there’s some difference between items on the internal USB bus versus externally connected devices.

Comment: This is on a desktop. It didn't occur to me that, because of the generic HID devices, it wouldn't be obvious, but the mouse is a real Logitech external USB mouse, and the keyboard is a real external Microsoft USB keyboard.

Comment: Fair enough. Very odd.

Comment: If you could disable the chipset the PC cannot function, it would crash, as with other hardware devices.

Comment: @Moab Disabling and re-enabling a USB controller, even one built into the chipset, doesn't "crash" the PC -- I do this all the time on the one that allows it, to reset the attached USB devices; that I can't do it on the other one is why I'm asking the question in the first place.